# How to move an already extant databricks notebook into a repo?

Tags: azure-databricks

Hoping this is on-topic, over the years I've only ever asked programming questions... but the on-topic URL says it is "software tools commonly used by programmers", so. Anyway, I have created a repo in github, and my databricks is linked to my github and all that.

However, I need to put a notebook I already made into that repo, and google is NOT helpful. I can only figure out how to make new notebooks inside the repo or import files; it's not letting me just put a repo in there.

I'm thinking I might be able to grab the url to the notebook from my workspace, but that gives me a relative URL that's just /x/x/x type stuff, not an absolute one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can simply use the UI to move the notebook present in your workspace (or not present in your repo) to the required location in your repo.
- Let's say I have a notebook called `nb1` in my workspace. In the options, you can see that there is an option called `Move`.

[image]

- Here you can select the desired location inside your repo by navigating through `Repos`.

[image]

- The Notebook will be moved to the repo. You can now navigate to branch and commit the changes made.

[image]

Comment: this option doesn't exist for me (anymore?) with the new UI. The Repos are not in the move diaglogue.

Answer (score 1):

Neither does it for me!
The only solution I've found was to export the notebook to a file and to reimport it.

Comment: Further, to merge changes from a workspace notebook to an existing repo notebook, I had to delete the notebook from the repo, then import, so it wouldn't rename it. It did handle the history correctly as an update when I pushed my changes (as I did not push in between).